# Spring Boot Actuator metric heap.used increases with every consequent actuator /metrics api call

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

One strange thing I observed. heap.used increases with every consequent /metrics api call. I am the only client using this application. Not sure why it is occurring. Can someone please explain?

"heap.used": 62495

"heap.used": 62642

"heap.used": 62827

Answer (score 3):

All sorts of intermediate objects are used in order to create your http response.  These objects get allocated on the heap. You should not be worried about this as garbage collection will clean them up.